# Blur UIImage to achieve effect like passcode blur of the wallpaper with swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uiblureffect

I want to achieve the effect that passcode view have (the wallpaper picture is blurred and darker)

This give me a black screen

```
func blurWithCoreImage(){

    var inputImage = CIImage(image: UIImage(named: "wallpaper"));

    // Apply gaussian blur filter with radius of 30
    var gaussianBlurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur");
    gaussianBlurFilter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: "inputImage")
    gaussianBlurFilter.setValue(30, forKey: "inputRadius")

    var context  =  CIContext(options:nil)
    var cgImage = context.createCGImage(gaussianBlurFilter.outputImage, fromRect: inputImage.extent())

    // Set up output context.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    var outputContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Invert image coordinates
    CGContextScaleCTM(outputContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(outputContext, 0, -self.view.frame.size.height);

    // Draw base image.
    CGContextDrawImage(outputContext, self.view.frame, cgImage);

    // Apply white tint
    CGContextSaveGState(outputContext);
    //  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(outputContext, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor!);

    CGContextFillRect(outputContext, self.view.frame);
    CGContextRestoreGState(outputContext);

    // Output image is ready.
    var outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    backgroundImg.image =  outputImage;
}
```

This function make the image to blur but allso shrink the image and is too far from effect in passcode view

```
func blurWithCoreImage2(){
    var ciimage = CIImage(image: UIImage(named: "passcode"))

    var filter = CIFilter(name:"CIGaussianBlur")

    filter.setDefaults()

    filter.setValue(ciimage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    filter.setValue(1, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

    var outputImage = filter.outputImage;

    var finalImage = UIImage(CIImage: outputImage);
    backgroundImg.image =  finalImage;
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

}
```

Comment: What versions of iOS do you need to support?

Comment: Ok, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you only need to support iOS 8 and above you can use the new `UIVisualEffectView`, which is the new built-in way of adding blur.

It's very easy to use, something like the following:

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurView.frame = myFrame
self.view.addSubview(blurView)
```

You can see that you can specifiy a `UIBlurEffectStyle`, which will allow you to make it darker as well.

Comment: How I can implement this with UIImage

Comment: You could simply add one of these `UIBlurEffectView`s over the top of your `UIImageView` - the image view would be visible, blurred, through the blur view.

Comment: Btw how I can delete the effect?

Comment: You could remove the blur view (`blurView.removeFromSuperview()`) or make it hidden (`blurView.hidden = true`).

Answer (score 2):

Try this to blur and crop image

```
func applyBlurEffect(image: UIImage){
var imageToBlur = CIImage(image: image)
var blurfilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
blurfilter.setValue(5, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
blurfilter.setValue(imageToBlur, forKey: "inputImage")
var resultImage = blurfilter.valueForKey("outputImage") as! CIImage
var blurredImage = UIImage(CIImage: resultImage)
var cropped:CIImage=resultImage.imageByCroppingToRect(CGRectMake(0, 0,imageToBlur.extent().size.width, imageToBlur.extent().size.height))
blurredImage = UIImage(CIImage: cropped)
self.backgroundImage.image = blurredImage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried updating the answer but it was nonsensically denied. Here's the latest syntax:

**Swift 3.1**

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
self.view.addSubview(blurView)
```