# Blur on UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, blur

How can I change the color of the blur in a UIImage? I need a black blur and I don't know how to do it. I found another answer here in Stackoverflow ([Blur UIImage to achieve effect like passcode blur of the wallpaper with swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26527411/blur-uiimage-to-achieve-effect-like-passcode-blur-of-the-wallpaper-with-swift/32393121#32393121)). This answer is perfect, but the blur is light and I need it to be black. Can anyone help me? 
PS: The code below is the answer from the other question.

```
func applyBlurEffect(image: UIImage){
   var imageToBlur = CIImage(image: image)
   var blurfilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
   blurfilter.setValue(5, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
   blurfilter.setValue(imageToBlur, forKey: "inputImage")
   var resultImage = blurfilter.valueForKey("outputImage") as! CIImage
   var blurredImage = UIImage(CIImage: resultImage)
   var cropped:CIImage=resultImage.imageByCroppingToRect(CGRectMake(0, 0,imageToBlur.extent().size.width, imageToBlur.extent().size.height))
   blurredImage = UIImage(CIImage: cropped)
   self.backgroundImage.image = blurredImage
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "blur color". Blur is a convolution, though you can create your custom convolution with color weights, it's much simpler to use default CIGaussianBlur filter + some color filter.

Answer (score 4):

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "example"))
imageView.frame = view.bounds
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
view.addSubview(imageView)

let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Dark)
let blurredEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurredEffectView.frame = imageView.bounds
view.addSubview(blurredEffectView)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the visual effect view is too dark. It is almost impossible to see the content behind. I need a blur effect that is possible to see through...

Comment: change let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Dark) to let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)